# Char() function in VB.NET returns value which is not same as Char$() function in VB6

Tags: .net, vb6

I am migrating VB6 application to .Net. In VB6 I have logic which takes values and returns corresponding Chr values. For example:

```
Chr(0)
```

However, when I use the same `Chr(0)` expression in VB.NET I don't see the same value I did in VB6. VB6 whould show a special character ``  but in VB.NET I see `vbNullChar`.

How can I convert this code to not change the original behavior?

Comment: Interesting... the post preview on Stack Overflow shows the special character, but it will not display after saving the post.

Comment: Also, IIRC, because .Net uses full Unicode encoding for strings by default, the .Net `Chr()` function would be equivalent to the vb6 `ChrW()`.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: Nope! VB .NET `Chr()` does code page conversion, but there is a `ChrW()`.

Comment: In my version of VBA (which if I am not mistake behaves the same as VB6) `?Asc(Chr(0))` returns `0` so whatever you are viewing it in is what is doing the conversion, it's not how it's stored in the string. Please provide a [mcve] otherwise it appears the behaviour is the same

Comment: You wrote "I don't see the same value" -- how are you trying to inspect the value?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this isn't just an IDE thing? Visual Studio reverse-folds constants, and `vbNullChar` is going to be what `"\0"` would be in C#, that is the string containing only the null character.